# Open default browser

Tags: android, android-intent

I am able to open default browser via intent but i'm facing a problem that, why url is first searching on google and if found then open that url via google searching.

My code is :

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("MY_URL")));
```

Please help.

Comment: Make sure that URL contains`http://`.

Comment: ys it contains http://

Comment: Wait! What do you mean by searching? Do you mean that it is opening a google search result page? or something else?

Comment: it is opening in google search result page...

Comment: Post the full code with URL!

Comment: the url is private so i can't post.

Comment: the url is open directly in google chrome but not in default web browser.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39900/discussion-between-harshit-rathi-and-ashu)